# Easy tables with Xamarin Forms - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am using [this tutorial](https://mindofai.github.io/Create-a-Backend-for-Xamarin.Forms-using-Azure-Mobile-App-Service/) in order to connect a xamarin.forms app with easy tables. I cannot add data to the database in Azure as i get

> System.InvalidOperationException

The error message is the following

> An insert operation on the item is already in the queue.

The exception happends in the following line of code.

```
await usersTable.InsertAsync(data);
```

In order to add a user

```
var user = new User {  Username = "username", Password = "password" };
bool x = await AddUser(user);
```

> AddUser

```
public async Task<bool> AddUser(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                await usersTable.InsertAsync(user);
                await SyncUsers();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(x.Message.ToString()).ShowAsync();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

> SyncUsers()

```
public async Task SyncUsers()
        {
            await usersTable.PullAsync("users", usersTable.CreateQuery());
            await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        }
```

> where

```
IMobileServiceSyncTable<User> usersTable;
 MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("url");
```

> Initialize

```
var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "DBNAME.db");
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
store.DefineTable<User>();
await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());
usersTable = client.GetSyncTable<User>();
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? Thanks! But, I think this is probably because the item is already added in your table.  Just a reminder, I'm not setting the value of Id.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your table. You probably have added the item already. Also, I would suggest that you don't set the Id property for your entity, because you might be inserting a same ID that's already existing in your table. It's probably the reason why the exception is appearing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I stopped setting the id and I get an MobileServicePushFailedException . Push operation has failed. See pushResult for details. I see my table from Azure portal and any item is added.

Comment: Sorry, were you able to add the item? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Although the first error message was displaying An insert operation on the item is already in the queue the database was not filled with any item. No i cannot add any information.

Comment: To be honest, I really need to see the code and check what's actually wrong.

Comment: I've seen the update. Can you also share the initialize method?

Comment: Can you update the dbname of this to anything? var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "AnyName.db");

Comment: I get the same MobileServicePushFailedException

Comment: That's odd. I'm starting to think the issue is either because of the data model or the actual mobile app table.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging you can do:

1) Turn on diagnostic logging in the backend and debug the backend: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter8/developing/#debugging-your-cloud-mobile-backend
2) Add a logging delegating handler in your MobileServiceClient setup: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#turning-on-diagnostic-logs

The MobileServicePushFailedException contains an inner exception that contains the actual error.  Normally, it is one of the 409/412 HTTP errors, which indicates a conflict.  However, it can also be a 404 (which means there is a mismatch between what your client is asking for and the table name in Easy Tables) or 500 (which means the server crashed, in which case the server-side diagnostic logs indicate why).

Easy Tables is just a Node.js service underneath the covers.

Comment: My InnerException is `{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.` . From the application logs `Error 404.0 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable`

Comment: Look at the URL being requested.  It will be something like /tables/users - if it is /tables/users, then the name of the table MUST be users - not user.  Generally, you need to add or remove an s on the end.